# Go TCP Listener ACL

Tags: go, tcp, filtering, acl, tcplistener

I realise I have a lot of invalid requests hitting my HTTP server but these are at TCP session and has not gone pass TLS handshake, hence no HTTP request yet. (I can't block it at HTTP layer).

I've written the below to filter malicious traffic at TCP Listener but I think its not optimum, the connection is first accepted and then closed, I like to completely not accept the connection if it comes from a known IP address. The next best is to do it at IPtables/NFtables, but I like to explore if I can filter remote addr prior to conn established at TCP Listener. I try looking at the NET package, and looks like its in the File Descriptor which isn't something easy to do.

```
func main() {
    // listen for incoming connections.
    l, err := net.Listen(CONN_TYPE, CONN_HOST+":"+CONN_PORT)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listening:", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

// Close the listener when application closes.
defer l.Close()
fmt.Println("listening on ", CONN_PORT)

for {
    //listen for an incoming connection.
    conn, err := l.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error accepting: ", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    
    fmt.Println(conn.RemoteAddr())
    p := fmt.Sprintln(conn.RemoteAddr())
    ip := strings.Split(p, ":")[0]
    if ip == "127.0.0.1" {
        conn.Close()
    }
    
    // Handle connections in a new goroutine.
    go handleRequest(conn)
    }
}
```

Comment: If your concern is about _malicious_ traffic, a simple piece of Go code is unlikely to help. There are lots of malicious things at the TCP layer that can be done before your code gets a chance to process it. It's probably easier and safer to push it down the stack and use a solution that's outside of your code and has been carefully designed for that.

Comment: Yeah, iptables/nftables and BPF on XDP/TC will do it better and at scale, however I don't manage the operating system. Looking at what I can do on the TCP Listener.

Comment: I found the answers in this article https://about.sourcegraph.com/go/gophercon-2019-socket-to-me-where-do-sockets-live-in-go/
My earlier understanding of conn retrieve from listener.Accept() is not quite correct. But there are a whole bunch possible options as highlighted in the article. Hopefully someone who wants to do socket level manipulation can find it helpful.